# libcurl sftp file upload resume issue

Tags: c, sftp, libcurl

I'm trying to develop a simple PoC (Proof of Concept) to perform an sftp file upload that supports resume of partially transferred files.

**Environemnt:**

```
GNU/Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64b
libcurl 7.58.0 built with libssh2 support
gcc 5.4.0
```

I took as a starting point the code example: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpuploadresume.html
and modified it to:

1. use the protocol string sftp
2. force resume branch (c=1) in the for() loop used to do the re-tries

The behavior I'm verifying is that once the connection is done:

1. the remote file size is truncated to zero after the first **curl_perform()** call (*that I understand is supposed to retrieve the remote file size* instead)
2. callback **getcontentlengthfunc()** is never called

I'm a bit confused by a comment as well:

```
  /*
   * With NOBODY and NOHEADER, libcurl will issue a SIZE
   * command, but the only way to retrieve the result is
   * to parse the returned Content-Length header. Thus,
   * getcontentlengthfunc(). We need discardfunc() above
   * because HEADER will dump the headers to stdout
   * without it.
   */
  curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L);
```

assuming the comment is correct, I would expect the option **CURLOPT_HEADER** to be set to **0L** instead.

I tried it as well but the behavior is the same described above.

**Update**

Just discovered on github that the above behavior is by design, because the SFTP protocol does not support the HEADER concept, so my question is, how can I use libcurl to retrieve the remote file size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several reading and interaction with curl mainteiner I solved the issue. 
A fully working example has been contributed to the curl project and kindly accepted. 
Here the details: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sftpuploadresume.html